# UIGestureRecognizers not responding

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a a number of pop up views saved as properties of a view controller. They are only added to the view when they are presented, and are removed from the view when they are hidden. Everything was working but i changed my code to simplify things and it's no longer working.

Here is an example of how I create and add my gesture recognizers:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hidePopUpView:)];
[self.totalPowerPopUpView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[self.co2PopUpView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

The views are presented by a selector triggered by pressing a UIButton (there is normally other code in the if statements setting the custom view properties, but I cut it out for simplicity):

```
- (void)showPopUpView:(UIButton*)sender
{
    CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400);
    UIView *popUpView;

    if (sender == self.totalPowerInfoButton)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:self.totalPowerPopUpView];
        popUpView = self.totalPowerPopUpView;
    }
    if (sender == self.co2LevelInfoButton)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:self.co2PopUpView];
        popUpView = self.co2PopUpView;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^ {
                         popUpView.alpha = 1.0;
                         popUpView.frame = endFrame;
                     }];
}
```

The popUpView's present, but the gesture recognizer selector doesn't get called when I tap them. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hidePopUpView:)];
[self.totalPowerPopUpView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hidePopUpView:)];
[self.co2PopUpView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Comment: Yes it does. I guess I can't attach a gesture recognizer to multiple views?

Comment: Yup exactly. It's because gesture recognizer has the view it is attached to as a property, and not a list of views, so only one can be attached.

Comment: @yuf Is this mentioned in any official documentation?

Comment: @skyline75489 You mean documentation saying gesture reccognizers can only be attached to one view? It sounds implied by the singular [view property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view).

Comment: @yuf That makes sense. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Double check and make sure the UIView you are adding the UIGestureRecognizer to has `UserInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`. i.e.

`[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`